# CSS gradient issue

Tags: css, opera, gradient

I used CSS gradient on one of my designs and it works pretty well. But there's a tiny problem - it looks messed up when the content in the page is less that the screen height. Can I define its height to be 100%?

I created that gradient on colorzilla and it seems pretty cross-broswer.

Comment: Can you JSFiddle an example of your code? Not much to go on as it is.

Comment: here. http://jsfiddle.net/Qa5Yp/ as you can see, the background keeps repeating accroding to height of the div instead of stretching over the whole screen. I hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: Finally, i figured it out.
using background-attachment:fixed; stretches the background :)

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use `background-attachment:fixed;` and boom - the background will stretch instead of tile.

Comment: Did adding also fix your Opera issue?  If not, you should ask a new question with pertinent details.

Comment: Opera issue is still not fixed. i'll create a new question